# Immutable ES7 global state store

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, react.js

I am quite an experienced developer but I am quite new to JS/frontend/functional programming and I am working with react-native in my day-job now.

I'm trying to do my own flux implementation to better understand redux. My goal is to have a performant data store that will behave predictably. This solution seems to be working for me, but will become slower the longer the app runs.

I've looked at using immutable.js and lodash but I'm not sure it's necessary. I've also considered using a mutable `currentState` variable and only merging the changes since the last call to `getState()` and then resetting i.e `changes = []` and updating `currentState`. I'd also like some opinions on my use of a promise in the `getState` function.

```
export default class Session {

  static changes = []

  static getState() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      resolve(this.changes.reduce((a, x) => Object.assign(a,x),{}))
    })
  }

  static update(value) {
    this.changes.push(value)
  }

  static showChanges() {
    this.changes.forEach((x)=> console.log(x))
  }
}



Object.defineProperty(Session, 'changes',{
  writable: false,
  enumerable: true
})
```

Comment: Why are you using a promise in `getState()` when it's a synchronous operation?  That will just make it slower than it needs to be and more complicated to use.

Comment: If the `reduce` function takes too long it will block the UI animations.

Comment: Using the promise doesn't keep `.reduce()` from blocking anything.  `.reduce()` is synchronous and JS is single thread.  The promise could keep whatever code comes next in the caller from blocking the repaint, but it's still really odd to force a synchronous object to use a promise for that purpose.  You could probably improve the speed of your `.reduce()` loop a lot.  Also single letter variable names like `a` and `x` do not contribute to the readability of your code by someone who doesn't know what you're trying to do.

Comment: I see what you mean. But just removing the promise won't fix the problem then. Do you think this solution would cause blocking if the array becomes too long? Do you think saving a copy of the latest state is a good way around this or would it be better to avoid mutable data? I agree that x and a are bad variable names but it's a convention in F# I got too used to.

Comment: If you have a specific problem that you were trying to solve with the promise, we can't really comment on that until you provide details on the problem (and it would belong in stackoverflow, not here).  Long array iterations can be processed in chunks (not with `.reduce()` though) to allow other things to run during the iteration.  But, that's a completely different question than you've provided info for and not really something for codereview either.

Comment: What is in `changes` and what is `getState()` supposed to return?

Comment: `changes` is an array of objects and `getState` will return a single object which reflects the latest state. `getState` will initially return `{}` and thereafter, the result of all elements in `updates` which is populated by `update` calls.
I will be using the class to store global state data such as the user's details after they have logged in, to use throughout the react-native application.

Comment: Does each object in `changes` contain the same properties, different properties or some properties in common, some not?

Comment: the objects in `changes` can have some in common and some not and will mostly be string data.

Comment: So, you want the union of all properties in the `changes` array with the later ones overwriting the older ones?  It might be simpler to just maintain that summary as you add each new item to `changes`.  Then, you don't have a time consuming process to build it from scratch when requested.

Comment: In case you haven't already seen it: part of the official Redux video tutorial demonstrates how to build an approximation of the Redux store: https://egghead.io/lessons/javascript-redux-implementing-store-from-scratch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting question:

- As per @jfriend00, using a promise is odd there. Your repaint might work out, but in essence JS runs .reduce() single threaded, there really is not a lot of value there
- Your `Session` is not immutable, it keeps updating the `changes` list
- All your methods are static, I would have expected an "Immutable" class with session as in instance of the `Immutable` class
- I would inside your class indeed maintain a mutable object that is up to date ( so a call to `update` would result in an update of both `changes` and say an object called `state` ) Since your class is mutable by having `changes`, you might as well go all the way.
- I like mutable.js, in that there is no such thing as `getState()`, you would get the new state from calling `update`. This way you can update the data and have the state in 1 line.

All in all, even after reading the whole immutable.js page, I don't see the point. If truly your goal is to have *A performant data store that will behave predictably.*, then a plain old Vanilla `Object` should do.